# How to find the filesystem block size?

Tags: c, gcc, filesystems

I wanted to know a way to find out what the disk's block size is through a function or a compiler constant in C.

Comment: Do you mean the filesystem's block size?

Comment: disks page size??? Do you mean cluster size? this would depend on the filesystem and filesystem settings/configuration

Comment: Yes sorry traduction mistake I meant the block size. I'm using the gcc compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The info about you using gcc compiler is not interesting, since compilers are not interested in the block size of the filesystem, they are not even aware of the fact that a filesystem can exist... the answer is system specific (MS Windows? GNU/Linux or other *nix/*nix like OS?); on POSIX you have the `stat` function, you can use it to have the stat struct, which contains the field `st_blksize` (blocksize for filesystem I/O) which could be what you're interested in.

**ADD**

Example

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  struct stat fi;
  stat("/", &fi);
  printf("%d\n", fi.st_blksize);
  return 0;
}
```

Tells you about the filesystem used on / (root); e.g. for me, it outputs 4096.

Comment: So in linux I could use this struct? I'm very sorry I'm a begginer. Could you use it in a example?

Comment: start reading e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat to see if it is what you want to know

Comment: Ok thanks i was really needeing it to complete a school project about structures on disk(tree b+, hashing, etc) thanks

Comment: it always says 4096...what is the equivalent for blockdev --getsize64

Answer (score 2):

statvfs() reports on a filesystem.  stat() reports on a given file.  Almost always this is going to be the same, but since you asked for the result from a filesystem the correct answer for POSIX systems is to call statvfs().

Comment: fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/r1sp1dbdg/sapdata31

vxfs

version: 5

f_bsize: 8192

f_frsize: 1024

Comment: I could not get the output above to format correctly.  Sorry. - HPUX vxfs may show that.